# Tense Present Simple is used at the current moment of speech

Tags: tense, sentence-structure

Well, in one of the books, I found interesting rule. In which it was written the next thing:

> For expressing action that appears at the current moment. When it
> describes events appearing directly at the current moment of speech -
> important one thing ascertaining of fact
>
> **Examples:**
>
> Here she comes.
>
> I repeat, I don’t know her.
>
> I swear it is the truth.
>
> Why do you ask?

From here on out, I dont understand, I literally dint feel the difference between for example "Here she is coming" and "Here she comes".

Can you explain me what is going on here?

Comment: I doubt many *native* speakers could "explain" the difference between *Here she comes* and *Here she is coming* - but they'd all know that the latter is idiomatically unlikely in most contexts. On the other hand, *There she is[,] dancing* is perfectly natural, whereas *There she dances* is either "poetic" or simply "weird", depending on the exact context. I don't know, but I *suspect* the difference might be to do with whether speaker cares more about the ***location*** *(here, there)* or the ***action*** *(coming, dancing).*

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think you can have copied this out of the book correctly, because what you've written doesn't make any sense. "important one thing ascertaining of fact" is word salad, not English.

But it sounds as if the book is oversimplifying, as books for learners often do.

Note that verbs of inner state or perception rarely take the progressive, so *I am not knowing her* never occurs in most varieties of English (though some speakers of Indian English say it, I believe).

The same applies to many verbs expressing speech acts: *swear* (and also *insist*, *claim*, and even *say* and *tell*, though they can occur with the progressive, often use the present simple even for single current acts. So *I swear that* is much more common than *I'm swearing that*. Here, *I swear it is the truth* is arguably a universal anyway, so the simple present fits: I'm having difficulty thinking of a context in which anybody would say *I'm swearing it is the truth*.

Finally, your first item, *Here she comes*: I think you should treat *Here/there [something or someone] comes/goes* as an idiom, functioning as a "presentative" - drawing people's attention to the thing or person coming or going. You can't use a progressive in the idiom.

Comment: You are right, book was russian. I had tryed to translate almost word by word. Unfoturnately as you said it is salad of words.
As I can see you describe another rule when verb can not be used in progressive tense(for example: see, hear, hate and etc). Then uses Present Simple. But I said about another rule...ehm ok, I use a google translate for it now.

Comment: And here it is: "To express an action that occurs at the time of speech, when describing events that occur immediately at the time of speech, only a statement of fact is important."